# Grab 5 latest posts from custom post type 'announcements'

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have a custom post type `announcements` which obviously holds posts with weekly announcements.

In my theme's header, I want to create a box which has the following semantics:

```
<div id="header-announcements">
    <h3>Announcements</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="post-permalink">Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="post-permalink">Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="post-permalink">Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="post-permalink">Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="post-permalink">Title</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div><a href="#">View More</a></div>
</div>
```

I know I want to use `wp_query()` and I've found that I should do something similar to

`ann-query = wp_query('post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5');`

I know I need to do a foreach, but I haven't dived deep enough into wordpress to know what to do after the query.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to call the loop and extract the information for each post e.g. the_title() etc. Also, first check if there is any result or not using have_posts() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, but isn't tested:

```
<div id="header-announcements">
<h3>Announcements</h3>
<?php
$queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5' );
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        $queryObject->the_post();
        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <div><a href="#">View More</a></div>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly, however when I copied and pasted, it threw a php error, but was easily fixed when adding `<?php` to line 15 of your code block. Thanks again!

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for fixing that. That's what I get for not testing :)

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful and much more elegant than other solutions I've seen. Though one complaint, when this is put within a post, it is unable to filter out the post that it is within from the list. Otherwise it's great!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a foreach loop since you this query give an array of objects, inside this loop you can use the properties of these objects for show the data. By example you can use:

```
$object->post_title, $object->post_content, $object->url
```